# Prove that for any set of $n$ integers, there exists a nonempty subset whose elements sum to a multiple of $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I have read various proofs for similar questions, but I cannot picture what is being said.  Can anyone break this proof down, or show a simple discrete example along with the proof?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the successive sums of the first number you happened to pick, the first and the second, etc.  You get a succession of $n$ partial sums.  If one of them is divisible by $n$, you are done.  Otherwise you have $n$ partial sums with only $n-1$ possible remainders when divided by $n$.  So take two with the same remainder.  Their difference...which is the sum of the numbers that are in the longer sum but not the shorter, is divisible by $n$.  QED

For example if $n=4$ and you take 1, 9, 5, 7, your partial sums are 1, 1+9=10, 1+9+5=15, and 1+9+5+7=22.  The remainders mod 4 are 1, 2, 3, and 2.  The second and fourth sums have the same remainder, so their difference...namely 5+7...is divisible by 4.

Comment: I added an example as you requested.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this has helped greatly!  For some reason I thought that if n=4, I look at all 2^4 subsets of 4, and work with this.  I didn't know it just meant choose any positive integers for the set size n.